# Big-O complexity for this loop

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, code-complexity

What's the big-O complexity for the following loop:

```
for each vertex u ∈ C do
        for each vertex v ∈ C and v > u do
```

What I'm doing here is imagine the following set {1,2,3,4} the loop executes a function for all the combinations of 2 elements of this numbers, (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4).

Is it =(n^2) where n is the number of elements in the set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is `O(n^2)`, assuming the function executed is `O(1)`, of course, and the iterator is also `O(1)` on average per iteration (which is usually a valid assumption).

Note that even if you optimize it further, you are going to process `Choose(n,2)` elements, and `Choose(n,2)=n(n-1)/2`, which is still in `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write an equation describing the number of combinations as a function of the size of the set.

Drop any lower-order terms and ignore any constant multipliers in your highest-order term.